# Why is this integration finite?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, mathematica

Consider $$\int_{2}^{2+\epsilon}\frac{1}{x^2-2^2}dx=\left.\frac{1}{4}\ln\left|\frac{x-2}{x+2}\right|\right|_2^{2+\epsilon}=\frac{1}{4}\left[\ln\left(\frac{\epsilon}{4+\epsilon}\right)-\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 2}\ln\left(\frac{x-2}{x+2}\right)\right]$$ for $\epsilon>0$. The limit in the bracket does not exist. However, Mathematica gives finite values for the integrations:

```
NIntegrate[1/(x^2/2-2^2/2),{x,2,2.3}]
```

```
74.7506
```

```
NIntegrate[1/(x^2/2-2^2/2),{x,2,3}]
```

```
74.6751
```

How Mathematica compute these integrations? And why integration value is decreasing even when the integration range is increasing?

Comment: The integral does not converge as you say. I do not have or use Mathematica so cannot help there.

Comment: `NIntegrate` performs numerical integration. I don't know if we can expect it to work on an improper integral like this.

Comment: See the accompanying error message: `Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small`. Compare your results to e.g. `Table[NIntegrate[1/(x^2 - 4), {x, 2, 2.3}, WorkingPrecision -> wp], {wp, {10, 25, 100, 1000}}]`